# Limits of integration for the radial wave function of the Hydrogen atom in the WKB approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, hydrogen, approximations

I am working a problem where we have to find the energy eigenvalues for the radial wave function of the hydrogen atom for $\ell=0$ using the WKB approximation. I am sure that I set up the integral properly, I am just a little confused as to how to find the limits. My integral is

$$
\int \sqrt{2m \left( E + \frac{e^2}{r}\right)}dr = \left( n + \frac 1 2\right) \hbar \pi.
$$

would it be

$0\ to\ r_0? $

Answer (score 0):

The limits of integration are  the turning points